# Trying to make screen scroll down with onclick, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Below is my HTML

```
 <div id="downbutton1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block">↓</button></div>
```

Below is my jquery.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $("#downbutton1").on("click",function() {
     $("body").scrollTop(757);
   });
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `$("body")`?

Comment: made the edit. doesn't work for $("body"). Tried putting a div class wrapped around called body just for a goof to see if something would happen and no dice.

Comment: Provide a link to your semi-working code. That's typically the way this works.

Comment: Well it doesn't work at all that's the issue. I want to be able to press the button shown (html) with the onclick (jquery) to make it scroll. The rest of my code is irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: The way you have your code setup is a bit strange. Did you mean to create the click handler outside of the scroll event? The way you have it, the click event will be constantly redefined each scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/qguhea02/1/

Your approach should be something like what action should trigger which function in order to achieve something.

In this case, you should trigger the click function when you click the button and after that, you scroll the body itself.

```
$("#downbutton1").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 757 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: make sure JQuery is included

Comment: it is. I have jquery working for a lot of other stuff so it is working just not this code line.

Comment: do you have any error in the console? check the linked jsfiddle example where you can see how I made it working

Comment: glad to hear it :)